# How do i automatically import JS and scss files when i include a .php component? (not using frameworks)

Tags: javascript, php, sass

I am a starting web developer. The company I work for makes relatively simple websites, some with blogs and/or products. We use our own CMS and don’t use a framework.

I am trying to improve the architecture/structure we use for websites. Which is currently done with a single stylesheet and a single JS file. Which is awful to work with for me because I can never find anything in these files.

So I started to separate these files into smaller scss and JS files. I’ve done some research. 
And i’d like to work with components Like this (preferably the first one):

[image]

I think this would work well for me because i am working in those 3 files at the same time, and then i don’t have to open them from different locations. Is this a good way to structure websites?

When i include the .php file for the component i would like to have it automatically call upon the right JS and scss files. This way i could move the component to a different website include it and it would work.

Is this possible? Is this even the right way to think about it?
And if not how do i go about importing or compiling JS and scss/css?

Comment: Can't you just hardcode `Carousel.php` to include the other two? Without knowing how your CMS works I don't think we can provide alternative solutions without just guessing wildly.

Comment: @ChrisG I thought of that, but then I'd have script files throughout the pages. wouldn't that be bad?

Comment: As long as you make sure that each script is properly isolated and only deals with its own component, it's not an issue from a technical POV.